# What is the name for the pattern where consecutive words link to similar resources?

Tags: hyperlinks, anti-patterns

What is the name for the pattern where consecutive words in a phrase are each hyper-linked to similar resources?

For example: [there](https://stackoverflow.com) [are](https://serverfault.com) [many](https://askubuntu.com) [sites](https://ux.stackexchange.com) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: [Cou](http://ux.stackexchange.com)[ld be w](http://stackoverflow.com)[orse](http://meta.stackexchange.com)[.](http://wikipedia.org)

Comment: Does this pattern have a name? Your question implies that it already has a name.

Comment: It's just a list of links, I don't think it has a specific name.

Answer (score -1):

I think that's a key feature of a [wiki style resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style/Linking).

> Linking through hyperlinks is an important feature of Wikipedia.
>   Internal links are used to bind the project together into an
>   interconnected whole. Interwiki links bind the project to sister
>   projects such as Wikisource, Wiktionary, and Wikipedia in other
>   languages; and external links bind Wikipedia to the World Wide Web.